# How to call CV_L2 in java?

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to implement this function in OpenCV where I can spot the differences between two images. I am trying to implement the same function in OpenCV Java (not JavaCV). I am stuck in implementing the "CV_L2" and from all my searches, the closest I come to is "Core.L2". Are these the same thing or how do I get Cv_L2? Thank you. Here is the code in the "Mastering OpenCV" book.

```
double getSimilarity(const Mat A, const Mat B) {
// Calculate the L2 relative error between the 2 images.
double errorL2 = norm(A, B, CV_L2);
// Scale the value since L2 is summed across all pixels.
double similarity = errorL2 / (double)(A.rows * A.cols);
return similarity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of CV_L2, try [Core.NORM_L2](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#NORM_L2)